# Using Application settings of Azure App Service resulting into an HTTP 500 error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I am using Shared tier to deploy my .NET Core web app to Azure.

Below is my app.config file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SASToken" value="" />
    <add key="StorageAccountPrimaryUri" value="" />
    <add key="StorageAccountSecondaryUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Under Application settings on Azure Portal, I have updated the following things,

[image]

But, when I access my API, I get Http 500 error with the below exception details,

`System.ArgumentException: The argument must not be empty string.
 Parameter name: sasToken
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(String paramName, String value)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials..ctor(String sasToken)
 at ProfileVariable.DataAccessor.AzureTableStorageAccount.TableStorageAccount.ConfigureAzureStorageAccount() in C:\Users\sranade\Source\Repos\ProfileVariableService\ProfileVariable.DataAccessor\AzureTableStorageAccount\TableStorageAccount.cs:line 22`

Comment: Is this a .NET Framework or .NET Core app? How are you accessing this value in the code?

Comment: This is a .NET Core App. And `var storageCred = new StorageCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SASToken"]);` this is how I access the values in the code.

Comment: I believe the portal application settings will update (at runtime) the `appsettings.json`, but not any `app.config` values.

Comment: Before publish  to azure, you should change `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SASToken"]` to use: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SASToken",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)`.

Comment: @Sameer Feel free to ask if my solution doesn't work, otherwise could you accept it to close your question?

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core web app, we usually put settings in `appsettings.json`.

```
{
  "SASToken": "TOKENHERE",
  "StorageAccountPrimaryUri":"CONNECTIONSTRING",
  ...
}
```

To get value in appsetting.json, leverage IConfiguration object injected.

1. Refactor your code with Interface and add IConfiguration field.

   ```
   public interface ITableStorageAccount { string Method(); }

   public class TableStorageAccount : ITableStorageAccount
   {

       private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

       public TableStorageAccount(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       // an example return table storage uri
       public string Method()
       {
           string cre = Configuration["SASToken"];
           CloudTableClient table = new CloudTableClient(new Uri("xxx"), new StorageCredentials(cre));
           return table.BaseUri.AbsolutePath;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Config dependency injection in startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       ...
       services.AddSingleton<ITableStorageAccount, TableStorageAccount>();
   }
   ```
3. Use the service in controller.

   ```
   private readonly ITableStorageAccount TableStorageAccount;

   public MyController(ITableStorageAccount TableStorageAccount)
   {
       this.TableStorageAccount = TableStorageAccount;
   }
   ```

In Program.cs template.

```
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

`CreateDefaultBuilder()` does the work of loading configurations like appsetting.json, see more details in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: I would add that, done this way, you will be able to override the settings via the Azure Portal in the way that you want